# inline-block displays centered in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a h2 and h3 elements that I want to display as inline-block. Here is the markup:

```
<div id="content" class="content-width">
    <h2 class="headline"> My Headline </h2>
    <h3 class="subheadline"> My Subheadline </h3>
    <table id="actions">
        ... some table content
    </table>
    <div> more content... </div>
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
div.content-width {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 900px;
}

h2.headline {
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
}

h3.subheadline {
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 0 8px;
    color: #b3b3b3;
}

table#actions {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 34px 0 0 0;
}
```

I thought this would display the h2 and h3 to the left, instead, the h2 is placed right in the center, h3 is next to it and the table floats under both h2 and h3 elements, as if both h2 and h3 were a block. This displays as I expect it in chrome.

Comment: Your code on http://www.jsfiddle.net would have make helping you a lot easier

Comment: Also, try giving div.content-width `text-align: left`

Comment: As per jsfiddle.net this code behaves the same on chrome and firefox http://jsfiddle.net/GeEvj/

Comment: Explain how you want the UI to layout a little better and people could easily help you using jsfiddle.

Comment: What Version of Firefox are you using? It looks fine to me in 14.0.1

![Firefox and Chrome Side By Side][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GglbB.png

Comment: According to the W3C, "h1–h6 elements must not be used to markup subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines unless intended to be the heading for a new section or subsection":  http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/common-idioms.html#sub-head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have anything else going on with the page?  What version of Firefox are you using?  I tested your code with FireFox 18.0.2 and got the results you are looking for, as you can see in this screenshot.  Well I tried to post an image, but since I am new here, my reputation isn't high enough to post images.  A one up would be appreciated.  Try a CSS reset.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry guys for not being as informative. It seems that there is a ul element outside of the container in my example that is affecting it. False alarm. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

try using vertical-align on your elements:

```
vertical-align: top;
```